# Twig add multiple filters?

Tags: php, twig

**is it possible to add multiple filters in twig ?**

for example i have this single filter

```
$app->twig->addFilter('_bah',new Twig_Filter_Function('_bah'));
```

if i want to add all my functions ill do this

```
$app->twig->addFilter('_bah1',new Twig_Filter_Function('_bah1'));
$app->twig->addFilter('_bah2',new Twig_Filter_Function('_bah2'));
..... etc
```

if i have many functions i want to use inside `Twig` template but without calling them by class name like `{{ classname.method }}` , i want to call them as a filter like `{{ "bla bla bla"|trim_me}}` is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extension in Twig...

> The main motivation for writing an extension is to move often used
>   code into a reusable class like adding support for
>   internationalization. An extension can define tags, filters, tests,
>   operators, global variables, functions, and node visitors.
>
> Creating an extension also makes for a better separation of code that
>   is executed at compilation time and code needed at runtime. As such,
>   it makes your code faster.
>
> Most of the time, it is useful to create a single extension for your
>   project, to host all the specific tags and filters you want to add to
>   Twig.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#creating-an-extension

Then you just need one line...

```
$twig->addExtension(new My_Twig_Extension_Class());
```